# Android - ThumbnailUtils.getThumbnail returns wrong image

Tags: android, thumbnails

Building an image gallery I'm facing a strange problem. I query for the images of an album like this:

```
String sortBy=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED+" desc";
String selection=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA +" like?";    
String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%"+folderPath+"%"};
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( uri, projection,  selection, selectionArgs, sortBy);
```

Afterwards I start to gather the images for all the ids I got from the query. I fetch a bitmap for a specific Image ID like this:

```
Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail( contentResolver, imageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

In most devices it works fine. Today I tested a Xiaomi Redmi 3 device this returns almost always the same thumbnail. So If an album has 200 pictures I get one or two correct and the rest are the same exact image.

However if I request MINI_KIND thumbnails they all return just fine.

What is causing this and how can I get around it ?

Comment: Same problem here on a Nexus 5 running CyanogenMod 14.1 (nightly build).

Comment: i m guessing it's a bug that can't be avoided so i used MINI_KIND and resized the bitmaps afterwards in MICRO_KIND size

Comment: Unfortunately, MINI_KIND is much slower. It would be nice, if getting a MICRO_KIND thumbnail caused an error, so I could first try this and then load a MINI_KIND thumbnail only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for our problem:

The large thumbnails (`MINI_KIND`) are stored in `DCIM/.thumbnails/*.jpg`.
The small thumbnails (`MICRO_KIND`) are stored in `DCIM/.thumbnails/.thumbdata*` and `.thumbindex*`. So after I deleted the files starting with `.thumbdata` and `.thumbindex`, my app could retrieve the correct `MICRO_KIND` thumbnails. The first time it's slow because thumbnails have to be created again. Apparently the old thumbnail files were corrupt.

Comment: Yes i know that..but It's not a solution if the user has to manualy delete that folder. By the way the default gallery app and some downloaded gallery apps were showing the correct thumbnail. I can't see any other way to do that if not by using the MINI_KIND...